# How clear data from a Firefox container?

Tags: firefox, multi-account-containers

Provisionally to remove data like:

- cache
- cookies
- ServiceWorkers
- storage

I remove the container and create it again, then I associate the pages of interest, the process is quite laborious.

I admit that there are rare times that I needed to clear the cache of something, but as I access ecommercers via containers, some websites sometimes change something and conflict with the cache or previous data, simply bugs from the developers, so I feel obliged to clear the Dice.

I would like to know if it is possible to clean the data in a container more efficiently, without having to remove it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "some websites sometimes change something and conflict with the cache or previous data, simply bugs from the developers, so I feel obliged to clear the Dice"? Containers is developed by Mozilla, so I'd be very surprised if it interfered with normal, proper caching. More info about your use-case might help folks engage with your question.

Comment: You should also consider filing a UX issue with the project: https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues

Comment: @Tom I didn't say anything about conflicting the cache of the container with another container or outside the container. I use a container for web development and other separate containers for normal navigation such as: "social networks" and "online shopping". The container that I want to clean the data on (sometimes, not always) is the container that I use for web development. But regardless of my goal what I want is to clear the cache and data only from a specific container.

Comment: So far what works for me is deleting a container and creating it again, but this is a bit more work. Perhaps the only way is for me to develop an addon so that it can control containers and data (but it will depend on the webextension API, which is something exclusive to Firefox), but that is already a matter for StackOverflow and not for SuperUser.

Answer (score 10):

This is the subject of a long-running issue report starting from 2017:
[Reset cache/cookies of containers without deleting them #303](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/303)

> It would be great to have an option to delete a container's data (cache/cookies/...) without recreating the container.

The last entry in the post dates from Apr 17, 2021, but to this date the issue
was not assigned to any developer, nor has any developer participated in the
discussion, nor has any workaround been suggested.

I do not believe that a solution exists for your question that is specific to one
container and does not affect all the containers.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I have a too new account to comment on the question so I have to use answer. There are several add-ons that you can get which should sort you out:

1. [Disposable containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/)
2. [Cookiebro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookiebro/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But temporary containers are different from having non-temporary containers that you simply want to clear cookies etc. In relation to Cookiebro, [Cookie autodelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/) also has a feature (experimental still, I think) for deleting cookies of the containers. I was hoping there'd be a non-addon way to do it, but as per harrymc's answer, maybe you're right, an addon will be the only solution

Comment: Actually, this addon here seems perfect: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/ it let's you see which cookies are in which containers and delete them (it's also recommended by Mozilla and has its source code on github). The only problem is that it's too focused on cookies; cache is totally ignored and you can't visualize localStorage like you can cookies

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but your issue is very specific. Maybe you could make a feature request on FF's or Cookie Quick Manager's Git page? I'm sure there are others out there that have the same needs.

Comment: harrymc's answer already links to a feature request:)

Comment: @flen's linked add-on fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

This Firefox  <kbd>Recommended</kbd> extension can be used to manage container specific cookies. You can also edit, protect and even backup cookies.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/

[image]
[image]